# Using javascript and html to create a graph that can be downloaded as jpg file

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to create a graph after receiving data from the server and can be saved as a jpg file? ex: creating a chart with the data received from the server and transform the chart to a jpg file

(I've checked highcharts.com, but when I right clicked on it's products I cannot download a jpg image. So I assume highcharts only creates a graph that cannot be downloaded as a jpg file)

Comment: Try [phantomJS](http://phantomjs.org). It does what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your situation, you may not need HTML nor JavaScript at all.

If the server is a Unix server you could generate the chart *on the server* using a very proven tool like `GNU Plot` which can output to various image formats. You could then present the user of your application with this image.

I even believe there is a `GNU Plot` version for Windows based servers as well.

Or, if you insist in drawing the chart with JavaScript, you could use famous libraries like `Flot` or `Protovis` to draw charts dynamically, client side and then use a tool like `canvas2image` to actually save the generated canvas chart or use the suggestion made in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf/3514404#3514404).